# Error during building an apk in android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, exception, apk, android-multidex

**here is the logcat error** can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error i am stuck in this from last two days. Thanks in advance.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class
```

This is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyLogin"><intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter></activity>
</application>
```

This is my build.gradle. Please tell me the error i have almost tried all the possible solutions. But of no use. please help! Thanks in advance. I have used multidexEnabled true; also but of no use as you can see below.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apkglobal.realsoftwaretestproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'widget'
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
```

Comment: post your gradle. You may be adding gradle multiple times.

Comment: May be issue with your gradle file

Comment: post your build.gradle, may be it contains duplicate dependencies

Comment: Upload your build.gradle of app level

Comment: Yeah i uploaded it. Please take a look.

Comment: change appcompat version to v7:27.0.1

Comment: do you have any files in your /libs folder. Can produce this duplicate error

Comment: Thanks @MinnuKaAnae it worked! Thanks alot